# hst:configurations not bootstrapped! Hippo CMS

Tags: hippocms

I've have a page "Contact" and I can already see it under my /bootstrap/configuration folder.
[image]

I've added the following to hippoecm-extension.xml under /bootstrap/configuration folder:

```
<!-- hst configuration nodes -->
  <sv:node sv:name="scc-hst-hosts">
    <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
      <sv:value>hippo:initializeitem</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="hippo:sequence" sv:type="Double">
      <sv:value>30052</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="hippo:contentresource" sv:type="String">
      <sv:value>hst/hosts.xml</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="hippo:contentroot" sv:type="String">
      <sv:value>/hst:hst</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="hippo:reloadonstartup" sv:type="Boolean">
      <sv:value>true</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="hippo:version" sv:type="String">
      <sv:value>2.01.15-SNAPSHOT</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
  </sv:node>
```

However, when I rebuild and start the project, the "Contact" page is still not there in the console!
[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referencing the correct file? It seems like you want to load a new page type but your xml is refering to a file called hosts.